# npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, npm, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, npm-install

I just created a Asp.Net core application. But I am getting an error as below while I run the command `npm install` in command tool.

> npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Can anyone please help me what may be the issue here. Do we need to change any proxy settings, if yes, can you please explain me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: how u added package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue. I wanted to set the `https-proxy` using `config` command, as I was using my company LAN network. Below was the command I ran.

**For https**

```
npm config set https-proxy http://yourpoxysettingsgoeshere:6050/
```

**For http**

```
npm config set proxy http://yourpoxysettingsgoeshere:6050/
```

You can also set the strict-ssl to false as below.

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

After running it, I was able to use the `npm install` command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Thank you.